# Sort list2 by list1

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing

I have list 1:

```
"John Doe"
"Jack Smith"
"Peter Miller"
```

and by using a function on each item:

```
List<Person> list2 = new List<Person>();
foreach(string name in list1) list2.Add(GetPersonByName(name));
```

I produced list 2 (shortened, the real one has 30+ properties):

```
{Name:"John Doe", Age:55, RoomNo:203}
{Name:"Jack Smith", Age:40, RoomNo:203}
{Name:"Peter Miller", Age:31, RoomNo:202}
```

So far, so good.

Now I decided to parallelize the execution:

```
List<Person> list2 = new List<Person>();
Parallel.ForEach(list1, person => { list2.Add(GetPersonByName(name)); });
```

which may result in an unordered list2.

How can I efficiently sort list2 to the same order that list1 had?

Or is there a way to tell the parallel foreach to do the list2.Add in the order of the input list? (The `GetPersonByName` function is the heavy one - but not calculation, mostly waiting.)

Comment: Does parallelizing offer any _measurable_ benefit?  If not then why not just keep it serial?

Comment: It does. When the list has 13 items, the difference is 6 vs. 12 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to parallelize the conversion using [`AsParallel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd413237(v=vs.100).aspx), [and use the order preservation technique](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677(v=vs.110).aspx) so that the order remains the same:

```
List<Person> list2 = list1.AsParallel().AsOrdered()
    .Select(name => GetPersonByName(name))
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT:** Added `.AsOrdered()` and a link to MSDN article in response to CSharpie's comment.

Comment: I was wrong, it maintains the order if you use the ToList. However, it does not when you use ForAll.

Comment: @CSharpie MSDN article says that your previous comment was right - i.e. that the reordering may happen as soon as you do `AsParallel`: ["By default, PLINQ does not preserve the order of the source sequence. In this regard, PLINQ resembles LINQ to SQL, but is unlike LINQ to Objects, which does preserve ordering."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Strangely i cannot reproduce it. It maintains order no matther what. Anyway, if they even specifiy this, its probably a good idea to use AsOrdered.